# Having a Babel Issue Deleted Lock.json reinstalled but still same

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

Error: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in
C:\Users...\node_modules\framer-motion\package.json
Code: ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED

Node v14.15.5 / Npm v6.14.11

Comment: How are you importing `framer-motion` in your code?

Comment: import { useViewportScroll, useSpring, useTransform } from 'framer-motion';

Comment: I downgrade the version of the node to 12.6.0 it has no problem at all. I think framer has webpack problem.